# How to use the get method with full url or subdomain in express?

Tags: node.js, express, url, redirect

I want to redirect someone on my Express app, but I need to check what goes before example.com, like cdn.example.com, api.sample.example.com, whatever, if anything, is in the path. How can I do this in the part of my app which deals with the routes? I can't figure out how to get this to work out in my testing environment either.

EDIT: I've tried:

```
routes.use(function forceMainSite(req, res, next) {
  //var host = req.get('Host');
  var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
  if (fullUrl === 'api.topics.example.com') {
    return res.redirect(301, 'example.com');
  }
  return next();
});
```

and this didn't work. I've also tried:

```
module.exports = function(app, hbs) {
    return {
        redirBadLinks: function(req,res,next){
            var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('Host') + req.originalUrl;
              if (fullUrl === 'http://sample.example.com') {
                res.redirect(301, 'example.com');
              }
              return;
        },
        ...
```

and that doesn't work either

Comment: Hi Jerry, could you add the code with what you have tried to the question? That way it will be easier to understand what your exact problem is

Comment: @AxelJunes I've added some code

Comment: Does your `req.get('host')` not work?  Or are your sub-domains not configured to hit the same server.

Comment: @jfriend00 thing is I'm also testing on localhost

Comment: Did you do local DNS config to make subdomains go to 127.0.0.1?  And is this only a local testing issue?  Right now, I can't tell if you're asking about subdomain config or accessing subdomain host name in Express after proper DNS already working and can't tell if only a localhost issue?

Comment: @jfriend00 you mean like on my computer itself? on my Mac, my DNS server is 192.168.10.1, the default setting. I want my app to see "sample.example.com" and go to "example.com" Or do you mean in the hosts file?

Comment: I cannot tell when you are asking about testing locally on same computer and testing with real public DNS.  Please edit your question to ask ONE clear question.  Also can't tell if this is a DNS question or an Express programming question.

Comment: @jfriend00 my question is how can I write middleware that will look at the subdomain and redirect elsewhere with status 301 if the subdomain is `sample`?

Comment: What part of your code is not working as desired?  Have you done any debugging at all to determine where you need help?  FYI `res.redirect()` expects a path or a full URL, not just a host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, this:

```
 if (fullUrl === 'sample.example.com')
```

will never match in either code because `fullUrl` starts with `req.protocol + '://'`.  You are trying to compare `http://sample.example.com` with `sample.example.com`

I'd suggest comparing only hostname.

Comment: would the hostname capture the sample in `sample.example.com`?

Comment: @JerryAtric - It should, but you can insert a `console.log(req.get('Host'))` and see for yourself.  This just sounds like you need to do your own debugging to see what you have in each string you are comparing.  You don't have to problem solve by only studying code.  Insert `console.log()` statements or breakpoints and examine actual values to see what's happening.

Comment: thanks; I got it and I voted your answer the best one